# How to strip out the IMDB id from a string in php?

Tags: php, regex

I have several thousand text strings where the IMDB occures in fairly random positions, but its always in the following format: tt0234215   (tt + some numbers).

What would be the best way to strip it out in php?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Probably by using a regular expression:

```
preg_match_all("/tt\\d{7,8}/", $string, $ids);
// $ids will be an array containing the matches
```

This will search the string for all instances of "tt" followed by exactly seven digits and return them as an array (extra digits will be ignored).  ([`preg_match_all` in the PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php))

Comment: @hopeseekr — D'oh!  Too much Python lately.  :-)

Comment: Wouldn't this fail with the movie "3 Ninjas" ?  That is to say it could potentially take too much information away

Comment: Dont really need to declare $id, and its gotta be #tt\\d+# but otherwise it works.

Comment: @Woot4Moo Good point...he could change it to: "tt\\d{7}", I believe.

Comment: @Yegor at al. — The declaration was just by way of example.  I've updated the code to be more correct and less confusing.

Comment: @user1028100 — The extra backslash is necessary when encoding the expression as a PHP string; it isn't part of the expression itself.